# Get last diploma for each employee

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the last diploma for each employee :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT e.employeeid,afd.AdminFileId ,afd.Title,ss.Name,YearObtained,afd.CreateDate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY afd.AdminFileId ORDER BY afd.CreateDate desc) AS rn
FROM AF_Degree afd
LEFT JOIN AF_AdminFile aaf ON afd.AdminFileId = aaf.AdminFileId
LEFT JOIN schools_School ss ON afd.SchoolId = ss.ID
LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.adminfileid=aaf.AdminFileId) AS D WHERE D.employeeid=109
```

The result of the above query :
**Case of EmployeeId= 109 :**

```
employeeid  AdminFileId Title                                                   School                                  YearObtained    CreateDate
107         149971      Intercambio universitario; Programa Erasmus ( meses)    Universidad Politécnica de Cartagena    2008            2018-05-14 03:45:41.6436995
107         149971      Student exchange                                        Umeå University                         2008            2018-06-27 16:01:53.8213765
107         149971      Erasmus Program (12months)                              POLITECNICA CARTAGENA                   2006            2018-06-27 16:01:53.8213765
```

**Case of EmployeeId= 139 :**

```
employeeid  AdminFileId Title                                                   School                                   YearObtained   CreateDate
139         145555      Electronic Business Engineering                         Czech University of Life Sciences Prague 2007           2018-05-14 03:45:41.6436995
139         145555      Entrepreneurship and Management                         Umeå University                          2009           2015-06-23 17:30:31.3100000
139         145555      Ingeniería técnica en informática de gestión            Czech University of Life Sciences Prague 2009           2015-06-23 17:30:31.3100000
```

For EmoloyeeId=109 the expected result is :

```
EmployeeId  AdminFileId Title               School          YearObtained  CreateDate
107         149971      Student exchange    Umeå University 2008          2018-06-27 16:01:53.8213765
```

For EmoloyeeId=139 the expected result is :

```
EmployeeId AdminFileId Title                                                      
139        7198        Ingeniería técnica en informática de gestión     Czech University of Life Sciences Prague    2009    2015-06-23 17:30:31.3100000
```

How to get the last diploma obtained for an employee based on the YearObtained and the CreateDate especially when we have two diplomas in the same year and having the same CreateDate like in the two cases mentioned above and their related expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `WHERE d.rn = 1` to the outer query. Also may need to change the partition just a bit to `... ORDER BY YearObtained DESC, afd.CreateDate DESC)...`

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT e.employeeid,afd.AdminFileId ,afd.Title,ss.Name,YearObtained,afd.CreateDate,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY afd.AdminFileId ORDER BY afd.CreateDate desc) AS rn
     FROM AF_Degree afd
     LEFT JOIN AF_AdminFile aaf ON afd.AdminFileId = aaf.AdminFileId
     LEFT JOIN schools_School ss ON afd.SchoolId = ss.ID
     LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.adminfileid=aaf.AdminFileId
) AS D 
WHERE d.rn = 1
```

That will get you one row. However, if there's the same `YearObtained` and `CreateDate` then it's not guaranteed which record you will get. You may need to add a third column to the `ORDER BY` in the partition such as an ID or something unique.